# Change a specific mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

So I've got this code, which changes my `type` column from `a` to `d` in my mysql database. But sadly, it changes even all the other `type` columns of all the other user ALTHOUGH I specified it with `WHERE id_user = X`(in the other codes, only the `WHERE id_user = X` varies like `WHERE id_user = 1`, `WHERE id_user = 2` etc.):

```
       <td><?php
if(isset($_POST['d'])){
$var2 = $_POST['d'];
$sql = "UPDATE users SET `type`= '$var2'  WHERE id_user = 2 ";
$mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
}
if(isset($_POST['a'])){
$var2 = $_POST['a'];
$sql = "UPDATE users SET `type`= '$var2'  WHERE id_user = 2 ";
$mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);

}
?>
<?php

 if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `type` FROM users WHERE id_user = 2 ")) {

    $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    }
    echo implode($r);
    echo implode($_POST);
?>
</td>
<td>
<form action="#" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" value="d" name="d"/>
   <input type="submit" value="--Inaktiv--"/>
</form>
<form action="#" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" value="a" name="a"/>
   <input type="submit" value=" --Aktiv-- "/>
</form>
```

Why does this happen and how do I change it the way, only the column of the right user changes? How do I determine the submit button to the specific `$sql = "UPDATE users SET`type`= '$var2'  WHERE id_user = X ";` ?

Comment: I notice `implode()`. Does your db contain comma separated values in the same row(s)?  You will need to post your db schema as well as values.

Comment: and what is the column type for `id_user`?

Comment: my `id_user` is a `int` with binary charset, my `type` is a `varchar` with charset `utf8`. There are no comma spearated values in the db.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. I notice `<td>` tags which suggests you may have more code. Make sure you don't have a caching issue. You don't have any js/ajax happening neither, do you? also try changing the charset. I don't know how this could happen.

Comment: Nah, I only have a table with these lines copied and replaced the `id_user = X";` . I think somehow the submit button (wherever I click it) activates all of the `if(isset($_POST['X']))` ? Is it possible to determine these submit button to a specific `if(isset($_POST['']))` ?

Comment: name your submit buttons with different names and add an extra conditional statement and if the value for it/them are equal to X and do a header redirect.